# Error: TypeError: must be str, not NoneType while Scraping list Links from website using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrape `https://ens.dk/en/our-services/oil-and-gas-related-data/monthly-and-yearly-production` this website.
there are 2 set of links `SI units` and `Oil Field units`

I have tried to scrape the list of links form `SI units` and created function called `get_gas_links`

```
import io
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs, SoupStrainer
import re

url = "https://ens.dk/en/our-services/oil-and-gas-related-data/monthly-and-yearly-production"

first_page = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(first_page.content)

def pasrse_page(link):
print(link)
df = pd.read_html(link, skiprows=1, headers=1)
return df

def get_gas_links():
glinks=[]
gas_links = soup.find_all("a", href = re.compile("si.htm"))

for i in gas_links:
    glinks.append("https://ens.dk/" + i.get("herf"))
return glinks

get_gas_links()
```

Main motive to `scrape 3 tables from every link` however before scraping table I am trying to scrape `list of links`

but it shows error : `TypeError: must be str, not NoneType`
[error_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdOuP.png)

Comment: `for i in gas_links:` `i.get("herf")` either sometimes return None or always does. Try to print `i.get("herf")` to see the value. Also is `"herf"` suppose to be `"href"`?

Comment: shows name error : `name 'i' is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong regex in a wrong way. That's why soup can not find any links that fulfills the criteria.
You can check the following source and validate the the extracted_link however you want.

```
def get_gas_links():
    glinks=[]
    gas_links = soup.find('table').find_all('a')
    for i in gas_links:
        extracted_link = i['href']
        #you can validate the extracted link however you want
        glinks.append("https://ens.dk/" + extracted_link)
    return glinks
```

Comment: any idea how to extract table from those list of links?  `https://ens.dk/sites/ens.dk/files/OlieGas/mp202112ofu.htm` this is one of the url.

Comment: @alex Just extract the table as a 2D matrix. You can easily find many solutions to convert bs4 table to python 2D list.

Comment: i have tried however, its not working out `def get_tables(get_gas_links):
    soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(get_gas_links())
    return soup.findAll('table')`